# Reading clipboard data on a button click in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a button(paste from clipboard), when I click on the button I need to read/get data from clipboard in typescript.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` will work in some browsers. However, many browsers where it does work will prompt the user as to whether or not they wish the web page to have access to the clipboard.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just use the (paste)="onPaste($event)" event binding on any HTML element in your component; the event parameter passed into your method will be of type ClipboardEvent.

**clipboardData** has been removed from the **window** type since typescript 1.5

Answer (score 0):

navigator.clipboard.readText().then(s => console.log(s));
This should work.